# Am I setting up the repository correctly for what our team is trying to do?

Tags: github

We have three developers working on a microsoft visual studio project that is being hosted on Github but we are using the VS Github extension tool.

We are a little confused about how many branches are necessary for our project.... This is what we have right now.

Master Branch -> Development Branch.

The idea that we are currently working with, is that we will each individually make changes, and then push up to the Development Branch to test with. When Coder 1 makes a change, Coder 2 and 3 will see the change and can merge their projects with the Dev branch and vice versa- so we stay in sync.... Then when we are comfortable with the changes, we merge Development Branch into Master Branch.

We are wondering if we need more branches, or if more branches would be userful....

For example what if we had:

Master Branch -> Development Branch -> Coder1 Branch, Coder2 Branch, Coder3 Branch.

---

Is there any benefit to adding more branches? We only have three coders and are wondering what the setup should look like.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With only three programmers, I believe everyone can work on the development branch at the same time as long as there's proper communication on what parts each are working on. Everyone can work on the development branch and when it's time to push their own changes, I advise:

- `git stash`, which will put your changes into a temporary stash and revert back to HEAD, pretending like you did not change anything
- `git pull`, which will pull the others' changes
- `git stash pop`, which will bring back your own changes. This way, you can build "on top" of other people's changes. If there's a merge conflict, "local" will be the other person's changes and "remote" will be your own changes.

But if you really want to be safe and formal, separate branches for each person can work, and using GitHub's page, it's easy to implement a pull request and do code review.

All in all, it just depends on how formal you want it to be.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your comment and the fact you helped me instead of instantly downvoting.

We are using the Visual Studio Github extension, and are working with the 2017 version that does not include stash functionality... Obviously the simple answer I suppose is just everyone upgrading to 2019.

When we try to "sync" our code, we aren't really sure what to do exactly.... Does pulling automatically incorporate the changes into your code? We have just been pulling and then syncing for good measure.

Since two of our teammembers don't have stash options. Do you advise anything else?

Comment: is there any actual benefit if we were to have each coder have his own branch, like I had described, that "merges" into development? Or does it just overcomplicate stuff?

Comment: @phitphatwhat I advise learning how to utilize the Git CLI; extremely useful when extensions fail to provide. Pulling automatically is a risk, because when there's a merge conflict, it gets MESSY. With just blatantly pulling and encountering a merge conflict, Git automatically creates a new branch, where you fix the error and then merge it back to the development branch, and then push those two commits. I simply advise just learning the Git command line, as that's built in. VSCode has the built in terminal, where you can type git commands!

Comment: There's a short term benefit and a long term risk. Short term is that no conflicts will arise as you cannot conflict with anyone if you're the only contributor on that branch. Long term is merging; lots of changes means bigger and messier files to merge.

Comment: To extend on my first comment, stashing will make sure that if there's a merge conflict, it will all stay on one branch instead of automatically creating a new one, and it will only create one commit.

Comment: Thank you, so you recommend sticking to the one development branch then?